# Python aioinflux `serialization.usertype.SchemaError: Can't have more than one timestamp-type attribute`, how to avoid it?

Tags: python, influxdb, influxdb-python, aioinflux

I have this `dataclass` with a `lineprotocol` schema like this:

```
from datetime import date, datetime
from aioinflux import lineprotocol, TIMEDT, TAG, FLOAT, MEASUREMENT, STR, INT
from dataclasses import dataclass
from shared import DEBUG_TABLE_NAME


@lineprotocol(
    schema=dict(
        timestamp=TIMEDT,
        measurement=MEASUREMENT,
        target_id=INT,
        type=TAG,
        weight=FLOAT,
        confidence=FLOAT,
        statement=TAG,
        now_time=TIMEDT,
        height=INT,
        dt_time=TIMEDT,
        success=TAG,
    )
)
@dataclass
class DataPoint:
    timestamp: datetime
    target_id: int
    type: str
    weight: float
    confidence: float
    statement: str
    now_time: datetime
    height: int
    dt_time: datetime
    success: str
    measurement: str = DEBUG_TABLE_NAME
```

but when trying to run the code i get this error:
`aioinflux.serialization.usertype.SchemaError: Can't have more than one timestamp-type attribute [~TIMEINT, ~TIMEDT, ~TIMESTR]`

I still need to have some other attributes like `now_time` and `dt_time` in, some short, of time format. But this seems to be raising an error for `aioinflux`. How can this be avoided?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Valid value types for fields are only: Float, Integer, UInteger, String, Boolean ([Reference](https://docs.influxdata.com/influxdb/v2.2/reference/syntax/line-protocol/#field-set))

What you can do, is to store the date either as an integer (timestamp) or a string (RFC3339 format).
You can then cast it back in Flux queries, if need be, using:

1. [`toTime()`](https://docs.influxdata.com/flux/v0.x/stdlib/universe/totime/) to conveniently convert `_value`
2. [`time()`](https://docs.influxdata.com/flux/v0.x/stdlib/universe/time/) to convert single values (e.g., within `map()`)